# what NAS cellera services to be monitered?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, storage, storage-area-network

We have a monitoring tool called SCOM which mainly monitors different OS related services .However, we being part of storage team would also like some of our services to be monitored.
We have  HP NAS , and I am wondering what all services I can ask the other team to monitor for us and alert us if something goes wrong.
The same goes with celerra and centera what important  services can be monitored .I did search but to no avail.I ‘m not finding any of the useful services..Any help in this regard is greatly appreaciated

thanks!

Comment: I thought you had a SAN, not a NAS, hence all the FC-related questions? HP have their own management tools which are great, same for EMC kit.

Comment: @chopper- thanks for the response.We 've both SAN and NAS environment. Can you name some of the services ,imp one, i need to ask them to moniter..it's completly new environment so..

Comment: well for HP I'd use HP StorageWorks, probably linked to HP SIM, less sure on the EMC side but call your sales team, they'll recommend something for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the EMC side the devices should already be setup to phone home if there is a problem (blown disk, etc).  EMC has some enterprise monitoring solution, but they are very expensive.  I'm not sure if they offer NaviAnalyzer for the Cellera or Centera systems (they run NaviSphere under the covers).  If they do, they look at purchasing that module, you can then export the data and process it and log it into a third party system.